# Subdomain, Pagination and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, pagination, subdomain

**in the name of God**

hi,

How i can transform this url

*domain.tld/blog.php?name=username&page=2*

to this one

*username.domain.tld/page/2*

with .htaccess?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

add the following directives to .htaccess file (create it if it does not exist) in the root directory of your website (domain.tld)

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]+)
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)
 RewriteRule ^blog.php$ http://%1.domain.tld/page/%2? [R=301,L,NC]
```